# Подскажите что не так,выдает код ошибки 3 (нет такого пути),хотя файл есть в текущей директории

Tags: ассемблер, dos

```
Dosseg  
model small  

.code  
    mov ax,@data  
    mov ds,ax ;секция кода  
    mov ah, 56h  
    ;функция DOS 0x56 для переименования файла  
    lea dx, orig ;загружаем в DX адрес исходного имени файла  
    lea di, new ;а в DI – адрес нового имени файла  
    int 21h  
    mov ah,04ch ;завершение программы  
    int 21h  
.data  
    orig db "text.txt",0  
    new db "C:\text.txt",0  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Функця `56h` требует адрес нового имени в `ES:DI`, а регистр `ES` у вас не инициализируется адресом сегмента данных.

Кроме того, проверьте что текущий диск - имено `C:`.

Comment: Спасибо исправил,но  теперь отказ доступе (ошибка 5)

Comment: @АлександрЯворский, ну так проверьте,что 1) файл `C:\text.txt` не существует 2) у вас есть права на запись в корень `C:` (под Windows может и не быть)